# Javascript - div innerHTML does not change

Tags: javascript, function, dom, switch-statement, innerhtml

```js
var score = 0, time = 1, heart = 3;

window.onload = function() {

  var input = document.getElementById("wordTyped");
  var timeLeft = document.getElementById("time");
  var life = document.getElementById("life");

  input.addEventListener("click", timer, false);

  function timer() {
    var id = setInterval(countdown, 10);

    function countdown() {
      input.removeEventListener("click", timer, false);
      timeLeft.innerHTML = "Time left: " + (time - 0.01).toFixed(2) + "s";
      time = 1 * (time - 0.01).toFixed(2);

      if (time == 0 && life.innerHTML == "") {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else if (time == 0) {
        --heart;
        time = 1;
        life(heart);
      }
    }

    function life(heart) {

      heart *= 1; // To make sure it is a number type
      console.log(heart);

      switch (heart) {
        case 2:
          life.innerHTML = "❤️❤️";
          console.log(life.innerHTML);
          break;
        case 1:
          life.innerHTML = "❤️";
          console.log(life.innerHTML);
          break;
        case 0:
        default:
          life.innerHTML = "";
          console.log(life.innerHTML);
          break;
      }
      /*if(heart === 2) {
        life.innerHTML = "❤️❤️";
      }
      else if(heart == 1) {
        life.innerHTML = "❤️";
      }
      else {
        life.innerHTML = "";
      }*/
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="wordGenerated">illustration</div>

<input id="wordTyped" type="text" />

<div id="time">Time left: 1.00s</div>

<div id="score">Score: 0</div>

<div id="life">❤️❤️❤️</div>
```

I'm not sure what is wrong within the `function life(heart)`.

I'm trying to decrease the amount of '❤️' by one as the time hit 0 and reset back to its original value, repeating until `heart` equals to 0.

If I use `life.innerHTML = " example "` outside the `function timer()` scope, it will work.

Using `console.log()`, it shows that `life.innerHTML` *has* changed, however, the display of HTML document stays the same and I don't understand why.

I've tried `.nodeValue`, `.innerText`, and `.textContent`, and all still gave the same result

Comment: You can't just add emojis to the code like that, use the html shortcut for them, like "&#x1F493;"

Comment: "You can't just add emojis" I loled. On a serious note, it still didn't change for some reason

Comment: @Teemu I use Bracket, I know its nothing professional compared to Atom, Electron and etc. but I think it will suffice for now. I'm still a newbie at this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a conflict usage with `life` variable and `life()` function. Change `life()` function name to something else like `updateLife()` and your code works,

**Note:** You can't have the same name for variable or function or Objects within the scopes.

**Demo**

```js
var score = 0, time = 1, heart = 3;

window.onload = function() {

  var input = document.getElementById("wordTyped");
  var timeLeft = document.getElementById("time");
  var life = document.getElementById("life");

  input.addEventListener("click", timer, false);

  function timer() {
    var id = setInterval(countdown, 10);

    function countdown() {
      input.removeEventListener("click", timer, false);
      timeLeft.innerHTML = "Time left: " + (time - 0.01).toFixed(2) + "s";
      time = 1 * (time - 0.01).toFixed(2);

      if (time == 0 && life.innerHTML == "") {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else if (time == 0) {
        --heart;
        time = 1;
        updateLife(heart);
      }
    }

    function updateLife(heart) {

      heart *= 1; // To make sure it is a number type
      console.log(heart);

      switch (heart) {
        case 2:
          life.innerHTML = "❤️❤️";
          console.log(life.innerHTML);
          break;
        case 1:
          life.innerHTML = "❤️";
          console.log(life.innerHTML);
          break;
        case 0:
        default:
          life.innerHTML = "";
          console.log(life.innerHTML);
          break;
      }
      /*if(heart === 2) {
        life.innerHTML = "❤️❤️";
      }
      else if(heart == 1) {
        life.innerHTML = "❤️";
      }
      else {
        life.innerHTML = "";
      }*/
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="wordGenerated">illustration</div>

<input id="wordTyped" type="text" />

<div id="time">Time left: 1.00s</div>

<div id="score">Score: 0</div>

<div id="life">❤️❤️❤️</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

there is a conflict between life and life function so you can go like $("#life").innerHTML="" or any thing else